# Google Maps API startup

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am trying to get the Google Maps API installed on a site.  I already have an API key from them.  I am using one of the 'sample' scripts from their website.  The map displays properly for a few seconds and then a 'oops, something went wrong' message displays...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Street View side-by-side</title>
<style>
html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
#map, #pano {
float: left;
height: 100%;
width: 45%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="pano"></div>
<script>

function initialize() {
var fenway = {lat: 42.345573, lng: -71.098326};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: fenway,
zoom: 14
});
var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
document.getElementById('pano'), {
position: fenway,
pov: {
heading: 34,
pitch: 10
}
});
map.setStreetView(panorama);
}
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_HERE&amp;callback=initialize">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated...this is very frustrating...the problem initially seemed to be with the "&" in the "src"...but I'm not sure anymore...I've tried so many fixes and variations...thanks in advance for 
any suggestions.  Regards.

---

Just as a test I took a 'static' example directly from the Google API examples...about as simple as you can get website where I am attempting to place a static map of NYC.  The map does NOT display...only the "alt" information ("Map")...what am I doing wrong here...????   This would make me think there is something wrong with my API key...???  (again as before I have not included my actual API Key in my example, however I have it in my HTML code on the page I am using here to test this)...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>HTML Tutorial</title>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>


<img src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400&maptype=hybrid&key=MY API KEY NOT SHOWN FOR SECURITY REASONS" alt="Map">

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.  Regards.

Comment: `MY_API_HERE` should be replaced with your api key.

Comment: The message also says _"See the JavaScript console for technical details"_. - Have you done this?

Comment: See my comment below, I do have my API key...I just do not have it inserted in my sample code above for security reasons.

Comment: I checked the source and at first it indicated the "&" needed to be escaped, and it was noted in red...now I have the "&amp;" inserted and it appears in a different color, however does not indicate an error.  I have seen others that seem to use the syntax in this way so I don't know why it would be an issue.  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Is there a way for me to check that JavaScript is running properly on my machine....?  I seem to have unexplained mysterious problems (like this) on my laptop when JS is involved...this is not the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already included your API key and still running into same error. Try checking your console logs, If the error says "ApiNotActivatedMapError" then you have to go to [API console](http://href=%22https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apiui/enabled) and enable "Google Maps JavaScript API" under your project.

You can follow the instruction in this documentation:
https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en&ref_topic=7013279

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in: `<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_HERE&amp;callback=initialize">
</script>`

You need to enter your API_KEY where MY_API_HERE is.

Comment: yes I know...thank you for the responses but that is NOT the issue...I DO have my API key inserted where it says "MY API KEY"...I just did not put it in my code posted above for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your reply anyway.  I have also tried to run by removing the 'callback' function...however still had problems.